# focus into element <td> with contentEditable

Tags: javascript, html

```
<td contenteditable="" data-model="phone_number">145</td>
```

I want the focus to dynamically generate a click event into this element 
[image]

I try this but no effect :

```
el.contentEditable = true;
el.click();  
el.focus();
```

Answer (score 4):

No need of `click()` just set `focus()` to the target element.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("el2");
el.contentEditable = true;
el.focus();
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="" data-model="phone_number" id='el1'>145</td>
    <td contenteditable="" data-model="phone_number" id='el2'>146</td>
    <td contenteditable="" data-model="phone_number" id='el3'>147</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/566x0w3x/2/). You need to encapsulate `td` in `table` and `tr`

```
var el = document.getElementById( "el1" );
el.contentEditable = true;
el.click();  
el.focus();

<table>
<tr>
<td contenteditable="" data-model="phone_number" id='el1'>145</td>
</tr>
</table>
```